# jQuery validate debug mode not showing any output in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

The following fiddle uses the jQuery validation plugin in debug mode.  When I press Submit, I don't get any debugging information in my console window.  Isn't there supposed to be debug information presented when debug = true?

[click to open the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jnku/)

**JS Code**

```
$("#paymentsform").validate({
    rules: {
        fullname: "required",
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        quantity1: {
            required: "#item1:filled",
            number: true
        },
        quantity2: {
            required: "#item2:filled",
            number: true
        },
        quantity3: {
            required: "#item3:filled",
            number: true
        },
        quantity4: {
            required: "#item4:filled",
            number: true
        },
        quantity5: {
            required: "#item5:filled",
            number: true
        },
        quantity6: {
            required: "#item6:filled",
            number: true
        },
        spam: {
            required: true,
            range: [4, 4]
        }

    },
    debug: true,
    messages: {

        quantity1: {

            required: jQuery.format("Required!"),
            number: jQuery.format("Number Required!")

        },
        quantity2: {

            required: jQuery.format("Required!"),
            number: jQuery.format("Number Required!")
        },
        quantity3: {

            required: jQuery.format("Required!"),
            number: jQuery.format("Number Required!")

        },
        quantity4: {

            required: jQuery.format("Required!"),
            number: jQuery.format("Number Required!")

        },
        quantity5: {

            required: jQuery.format("Required!"),
            number: jQuery.format("Number Required!")

        },
        quantity6: {

            required: jQuery.format("Required!"),
            number: jQuery.format("Number Required!")

        },
        spam: {

            range: jQuery.format("Wrong answer!")
        }
    }
});
$("#item1").click(function() {
    $("#quantity1").valid();
});
$("#item2").click(function() {
    $("#quantity2").valid();
});
$("#item3").click(function() {
    $("#quantity3").valid();
});
$("#item4").click(function() {
    $("#quantity4").valid();
});
$("#item5").click(function() {
    $("#quantity5").valid();
});
$("#item6").click(function() {
    $("#quantity6").valid();
});
```

Comment: `debug` option is for error in settings, not regarding fields validation. e.g: http://jsfiddle.net/8Jnku/4/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Quote OP**:

> *"Isn't there supposed to be debug information presented when debug = true?"*

Yes, but I'm not sure what you're expecting it to do when there is nothing to debug.

[As per documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#debug):

> **debug**: Enables debug mode. If true, the form is not submitted and *certain errors* are displayed on the console (will check if a window.console property exists). Try to enable when a form is just submitted instead of validation stopping the submit.

In other words, `debug:true` will block submission, and it will only tell you when you've incorrectly set some of the options.   It tries to "debug" your validation code.  It will not display anything in the console when the plugin method is working/constructed properly.

---

**EDIT**:  This is how `debug` works...

[I've set one of your fields to an invalid method I called `fooBar`](http://jsfiddle.net/8Jnku/5/):

```
fullname: "fooBar",
```

Console Log:

> exception occured when checking element fullname, check the 'fooBar' method >
>   Error

Comment: Thank you for adding some information, I confused when my form is valid but it's not submited for no reason and I seek again the debug:true, and turn it off, it's the culprit of my form wasn't submitted. Thank you !